# Generator not creating any output in Python

Tags: python, output, generator

I'm trying to use the following generator but it isn't producing any output. Ideas? Thank you

```
def generate_numbers(number):
"""To generate numbers"""
for i in range(number):
    ratings = []
    for j in categories:
        ratings.append(random.randint(0, 5))
    score = list(zip(categories, ratings))
    filtered_score = (s for s in score if s[1] != 0)
    yield filtered_score
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is pretty odd in a few respects, one of which is that it does a lot of work upfront to build `ratings` which seems unnecessary, defeating the purpose of the generator. Secondly, are you sure you want to return a nested generator? What are you trying to accomplish exactly and how are you calling this? I get output, but of course it's a bunch of generator objects that need to be yielded from. I'm guessing you meant `return filtered_score` and call it with `print(list(generate_numbers(10)))` but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to yield each entry in the final filtered set.

Try this code:

```
import random

def generate_numbers(number):
    """To generate numbers"""
    categories = ['a','b','c','d','e']
    for i in range(number):
        ratings = []
        for j in categories:
            ratings.append(random.randint(0, 5))
        score = list(zip(categories, ratings))
        for fs in (s for s in score if s[1] != 0):
            yield fs
        
for x in generate_numbers(3):
    print(x)
```

Output

```
('a', 4)
('c', 1)
('d', 4)
('e', 4)
('a', 2)
('b', 3)
('c', 4)
('d', 3)
('e', 1)
('b', 1)
('c', 4)
('d', 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: You are returning a generator object and not value(s).

There's several different ways you can fix this. Two straight forward ones are

1. In the calling function, use two loops instead of one (corresponding to the two used in the function).

   ```py
   for x in generate_numbers(5):
     for y in x:
       print(y)
   ```
2. In the function change the second last line so that you are creating a `list` or something rather than a generator

   ```py
   filtered_score = [s for s in score if s[1] != 0] # notice the use of square brackets
   ```

P.S. Use any one of the two methods and not both!